# from boruta import Borutapy, Error : No module named Boruta found

Tags: python

I did :

```
pip install boruta
```

it worked perfectly fine and it got installed. But when i try to run

```
from Boruta import BorutaPy
```

it gives an error : No module named 'Boruta'. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

`from boruta import BorutaPy`

Casing is important.

Comment: Solved! Thank You!

Comment: Consider accepting the answer that worked.

Answer (score 0):

run `pip show boruta` this will show information about boruta of course but if it shows  `no module named boruta found` run `pip install boruta` . If the module is found then uninstall it [`pip uninstall boruta`] and reinstall it

also run `pip freeze` to list all the modules.

in installation you run `pip install boruta` and in your file you just used `from Boruta import BorutaPy`